# Creating data with linked tables with foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables in my MySql Workbench database : station, location and locationstation. The id of station and location are foreign key to locationstation. The problem is that when I select the stationName and locationName, I can't get to save it into the locationstation table. Any help with that? Thanks!

This is the code that I linked the names of the station and location into combo box for the user to select.

```
 private void Create_LS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            var storeStation = (from SLS in Setupctx.stations
                               select SLS.StationName).Distinct().ToList();                                   
            foreach (var LocationStation in storeStation)
            {
                cbStation.Items.Add(LocationStation);
            }

            var storeLocation1 = (from SLS in Setupctx.stations
                                join location l in Setupctx.locations on SLS.StationID equals l.LocationID
                                select l.LocationName).Distinct().ToList();                                      
            foreach (var LocationStation1 in storeLocation1)
            {
                cbLocation.Items.Add(LocationStation1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the codes to create.

```
 private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            locationstation ls = new locationstation();
            ls.stationID = cbStation.SelectedIndex;
            ls.locationID = cbLocation.SelectedIndex;
            Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(ls);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            cbStation.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cbLocation.SelectedIndex = -1;

            MessageBox.Show("New Location Station Is Created");
        }
    }
```

This is the codes that I set the station and location into dictionary.

```
private void cbStation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Dictionary<int, string> dictStation = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dictStation.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["StationID"].ToString()), dr["StationName"].ToString());
        }

        dictStation.Equals((cbStation.SelectedValue));
    }

    private void cbLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        Dictionary<int, string> dictStation = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dictStation.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["LocationID"].ToString()), dr["LocationName"].ToString());
        }

        dictStation.Equals((cbLocation.SelectedValue));
    }
```

The error is the part: "(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)". They can't find table[0]. Any opinion of what't the error is about?

Comment: You only create data sets and don't fill them in any way. What do you expect `dictStation.Equals` to do?